# Customize VLC interface permanently

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vlc-media-player, user-interface, toolbar

Running Ubuntu 18.04 and I'd like to add/remove some toolbar elements in VLC 3.0.1 interface.

I go under ***Tools-> Customize Interface...***, do my job, click the ***Close*** and my interface changes; however, if I close VLC and re-open it, the interface is still the standard one.

Anyone knows how I can solve it?

Comment: Have you ***created a new profile OR customizing existing one*** ? 
 Would suggest to create a new profile and do customizattion there, So that you don't mess up with existing ones.

Comment: @C0deDaedalus Yes, I tried also that way! But nothing changed at reboot